# How to generate a standalone PDF animation?

Tags: animations, animate

I have a PDF file consisting of several pages. How to generate a standalone PDF animating those pages?

## More detailed skenario

I create a bunch of diagrams everyday. Sometimes I want to animate each diagram in either GIF or PDF. It will be tedious if I have to create a new file as follows

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}% cannot use preview
\usepackage{animate,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[palindrome,controls,loop,autoplay,scale=<scale>]{<frame rate>}{"<diagram filename>"}{}{}
\end{document}
```

whenever I want to create a standalone PDF animation.

Is there any workflow to simplify this?

Comment: related : How to create simple animations with `animate`? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401886/138900

Comment: Yours is too short: we don't know on which operating system you are running the batch: Mac, Unix, Windows, Linux? mine answers the question that was asked by being as simple as possible and as short as possible (if it is possible to answer such a question in a short way) and it is completely independent of the operating system.

Comment: In my answer I give two different ways to use the animate package. It's true that it's a long time. Should I cut this answer in half and write two answers instead of one?

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment but the point was that I think the answer given by AndreC should be split into several shorter answers for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Microsoft Windows Users

For other operating systems, please rise your both hands.

Create a template file, name it `template.tex`, save it below the local texmf folder (I am not sure my terminology is correct here).

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}% cannot use preview
\usepackage{animate,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[palindrome,controls,loop,autoplay,scale=\OutputScale]{\FrameRate}{"\InputFileName"}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Create a batch file as follows. Name it, for example, `animator.bat`. Save it in any safe place and register its path to `PATH` to make it accessible from everywhere.

```
echo off

rem %1 PDF filename without extension
rem %2 frame rate
rem %3 scale

if exist "%~1.pdf" rename "%~1.pdf" "%~1-animate.pdf"

rem need 2 compilations
if exist "%~1-animate.pdf" pdflatex -interaction=batchmode --jobname="%~1" "\def\InputFileName{%~1-animate}\def\FrameRate{%2}\def\OutputScale{%3}\input{template}"
if exist "%~1-animate.pdf" pdflatex --jobname="%~1" "\def\InputFileName{%~1-animate}\def\FrameRate{%2}\def\OutputScale{%3}\input{template}"

if exist "%~1-animate.pdf" del "%~1-animate.pdf"

for %%x in (aux log out toc) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

Now you can call the batch `animator.bat` as follows.

`animator mypdffilenamewithoutextension 25 1`

Done, see the result. A standalone PDF animation viewed on Acrobat Reader.

[image]

## Miscellaneous

You can also create a new build profile (in TeXnicCenter, TeXStudio, or any editors) to invoke the batch such that you can save more time and energy.

Comment: now the hard part: convert this into some file having a decent extension such as ".sh" for Linux :)