# Set coordinate boundaries of tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

From my small experience with tikz in Latex, it seems that the boundary of a tikz image is set automatically based on its contents. This caused me some trouble when I was trying to scale and align multiple tikz images.

Is there a way to set the boundary manually? For instance perhaps I want an image with nodes at (1,1) and (2,1) and a boundary which is rectangular with corners at (0,0) and (3,2). How would this be achieved?

Comment: give a _complete_ example!

Comment: `\clip (-0,05) rectangle (3,2);` welcome to tex.se!

Comment: `\path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);` See p. 175 of the pgfmanual for more details.

Comment: Thanks all! Zarko's answer did the trick. @Zarko: Did you want to move your comment to an answer?

Comment: of course i can, but this can be easy to do if you provide some mwe ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use of `clip` you can see from the following example from *TikZ & PGF Manuall, v 3.0.1A*, page 140:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\draw [name path=curve 1] (-2,-1) .. controls (8,-1) and (-8,1) .. (2,1);
\draw [name path=curve 2] (-1,-2) .. controls (-1,8) and (1,-8) .. (1,2);
\fill [name intersections={
of=curve 1 and curve 2,
by={[label=center:a],[label=center:...],[label=center:i]}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

description you can find in chapter *15 Actions on Paths*, page 164 of aforementioned manual.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `use as bounding box` *(see page 175 of the 3.0.1a manual)* and its shortcut `\useasboundingbox` `(see page 164)`

Example taken from page 236 of the manual:
[image: use as bounding box]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\draw[help lines,use as bounding box] (0,-.5) grid (4,5);
\draw (0.5,0) .. controls (9,6) and (-5,6) .. (3.5,0)
node foreach \pos in {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1}
[pos=\pos,swap,fill=red!20] {\pos}
node foreach \pos in {0.025,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.975}
[pos=\pos,fill=blue!20] {\pos};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just include the desired margin coordinates in any path and the resulting `tikzpicture` will include it in final `bounding box`. In following picture, a phantom path is drawn and included in final box (shown in black with `show background rectangle`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\draw[red] (1,1) rectangle ++(1,1);
\path(0,0) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]