# Animate package for latex

Tags: beamer, animate

I would like to learn  how to use the animate package, I need a person can teach me, please I need this, help me. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the `animate` manual?

Comment: Have a look at an example I did a while ago: https://www.uweziegenhagen.de/?p=3048

Comment: yeah I saw, but I dont understand why I need a Xplain about it.

Comment: Please, explain me :)

Comment: [How to create simple animations with `animate`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401886/134144) should be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Below, there are three basic examples to get you started. They compile out of the box.

Animations can be made from inline code, using the `animateinline` environment, and from external graphics files, using the `\animategraphics` command.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls=play,loop,scale=3]{1}
  \fbox{0}
\newframe  
  \fbox{1}
\newframe  
  \fbox{2}
\newframe  
  \fbox{3}
\newframe  
  \fbox{4}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

same result, but using parameterized code in a `\multiframe` loop:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone} 
 
\usepackage{animate} 
 
\begin{document} 
 
\begin{animateinline}[controls=play,loop,scale=3]{1} 
  \multiframe{5}{i=0+1}{\fbox{\i}} 
\end{animateinline} 
 
\end{document}
```

from external multi-page PDF file:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone} 
 
\usepackage{animate} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
 
\begin{document} 
\animategraphics[ 
  controls=play, 
  width=1.5cm 
]{1}{example-image-a4-numbered}{0}{4} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first \fbox{0} code compiles but not annimate, either on overleaf or xchange pdf viewer.