# animate package cannot find the png file

Tags: graphics, animations, animate, gif

I use `Ubuntu 22.04` and `TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022)`.

I want to embed [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fourier_series_and_transform.gif) "GIF" file as animation in output PDF file. I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401900/114216) post:

1. `$ convert ./Fourier_series_and_transform.gif -coalesce Fourier.png` This products 93 PNG files: From `Fourier-0.png` to `Fourier-92.png`
2. Wrote these in `Untitled-4.tex`:

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[step]{animate}

   \begin{document}
   \animategraphics[width=\linewidth]{12}{Fourier-}{0}{92}%
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Built the doc: `$ latex ./Untitled-4.tex`

But I encounter with this error:

```
! Package animate Error: None of the files
(animate)                `Fourier-0.eps',
(animate)                `Fourier-0.mps' or
(animate)                `Fourier-0.ps'
(animate)                could be found.
(animate)                Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?.
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Since the engine looks for Postscript files exclusively, you seem to use the wrong command  (`latex`) to typeset the document. PNG inclusion requires `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you for your time. I added both `controls,loop` and try to build the document with `xelatex` and `pdflatex`. Now first frame is visible; but I cannot animate it even by clicking. I test that in "Firefox", "Evince" and "Chrome". Can you help me?

Comment: On Linux, the only PDF viewer supporting this kind of animations is KDE Okular. You might also want to try SVG output instead of PDF; here, animations are supported across the web browsers that you have mentioned. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235180